# Is java constructor static?

Tags: java, class, methods, constructor, static

While reading bruce eckel, thinking in java, i found a statement in chapter initialization and cleanup which said -
constructors in java are actually static.

How can this be true? Or is this error on authors part.

Comment: @sweeper the second duplicate directly addresses the quote in Eckels book